# Fastest Freely Redistributable Database for Java

Tags: java, database

I'm looking for the best database software for a new open source application. The primary criteria is it has to be lightning fast for searching among tens of thousands of entries. Ideally it would be entirely Java based but simply having a Java API is OK. I'm looking to license under GPL so the project would have to be compatible with that. So far SQLite seems to be the most ubiquitous solution but I don't want to overlook something else if it could turn out to be better.

When I search the general internet, most results seems to be for object databases. I don't care if the database is object-based or relational, and I don't *think* I care if it's "NoSQL" . I have lots of experience with MySQL but I'm not terribly afraid of learning a new query language or interface if it's faster that way. The main kind of data this will be managing is filenames with at least 20 metadata fields attached; I'd want to have multiple datasets with the same fields, and it would be nice to also store some application preferences in the database.

I see from some responses that there may be confusion about my (former) use of "embedded" in the title. I want to clarify that I mean "embedded in the application and redistributed" and not "in use on an embedded device." The application is currently targeting full scale computers, although one reason for "ideally it would be entirely java based" is a dreamy aspiration of creating an Android version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.polepos.org/ there is a [benchmark](http://polepos.sourceforge.net/results/PolePositionEmbedded.pdf) which clains thathttp://www.db4o.com/
is one of the fastest embedded dbs.

I personally worked with db4o and its very nice and its licensed under GPL so it should possibly fit your needs

Comment: However their information only applicable on the platform they tested it on. It could vary on different platforms and how its being used. These tests went up to 3000 records and OP says it will to be fast with tens of thousands of records. In addition SQLite beat out db4o in some tests so its best for the OP to do his\her own testing to determine which best fits his\her needs.

Comment: So, if I'm reading the example results correctly, SQLite is the fastest in general, db4o is the fastest for object-oriented data, and HSQLDB is fastest for flat data. Is that about right? Does anybody have any experience that confirms or denies this?

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately it really depends on your application. SQLite is not designed to be as robust as standard client\server databases like Oracle and MySQL. From the FAQ for SQLite they say the following on the subject:

> However, client/server database engines (such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, or Oracle) usually support a higher level of concurrency and allow multiple processes to be writing to the same database at the same time. This is possible in a client/server database because there is always a single well-controlled server process available to coordinate access. If your application has a need for a lot of concurrency, then you should consider using a client/server database. But experience suggests that most applications need much less concurrency than their designers imagine.

That being said SQLite is very fast but then again this depends on how you'll be using it and on what platforms. If you are running on an embedded device you may see significant performance differences than when running on a regular desktop\server which is why its hard to give a exact answer. SQlite does see significant performance gains from *not* abiding to the standard client\server model.

Your best bet is to pick a few, like SQLite, PostgreSQL, MySQL, and see the performance implications of each by running some tests which simulate common scenarios you will encounter in you application.