# Developing Swing Application tool with MS Access DB

Tags: java, swing, jakarta-ee, ms-word, swingworker

I am planning to develop a swing application tool ie. Expense calculator or software for personal use.
Is it possible to create such application so that I will talk with MS Access database to store data and once it is developed and i will be bundling it into jar or exe file.
So when copying the jar or exe file to some other laptop or system I dont want to configure the DSN name or connection setting to MS Access in each system where i am going to put the file.
instead on click of the exe or jar file the connection will be set automatically  I mean the exe or jar should independently on each system where i am going to run it
( Is it feasible in Java )

Comment: Yes it is feasible once you start exploring some thing

Comment: Also consider an [embedded database](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7421852/230513).